# UserWay does not respect the `translate` HTML attribute

Tags: userway

We are using UserWay to provide accessibility and translation features for a clients site. However, certain text should not be translated, eg peoples names. We have added `translate="no"` to these HTML elements, however, UserWay is still translating them.

Google Translate seems to respect the tags no problem.

Does anyone know of a way to get UserWay to ignore certain bits of text?